# Python Twisted web server audio file

Tags: python, twisted, m4a, twisted.web

I am trying to create a simple web server with twisted in python.  I am having trouble serving an m4a audio file though.

In the current program, when I load http://localhost:8880/mp3.html, it works fine.  It shows the audio player and the mp3 plays.  In addition, the program prints both "/mp3.html" and "/test.mp3".

However, when I load http://localhost:8880/m4a.html, it doesn't work.  It shows the audio player, but the m4a doesn't play.  In addition, the program prints only "/m4a.html" and not "/test.m4a".

My current code is below.

```
import urlparse
import os
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.static import File
import time
import subprocess
import mimetypes

class playM4A(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        this=urlparse.urlparse(request.path)#scheme,netloc,path,query
        root,ext=os.path.splitext(this.path)
        filename=os.path.basename(request.path)
        fileFolder=request.path.replace(filename,"")
        self.serverRoot=os.getcwd()
        print request.path
        if ext==".m4a":
            thisFile=File(self.serverRoot+request.path)
            return File.render_GET(thisFile,request)
        elif ext==".mp3":
            thisFile=File(self.serverRoot+request.path)
            return File.render_GET(thisFile,request)
        elif filename=="m4a.html":
            return """
<html>
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://localhost:8880/test.m4a" type="audio/mp4a-latm">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
not m4a </html>"""
        elif filename=="mp3.html":
            return """
<html>
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://localhost:8880/test.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
not m4a </html>"""

resource = playM4A()
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: It seems to work with an mp3, so I think it may have something to do with the m4a file format.

Comment: I suspect that the `Content-Type:` header is incorrect. Can you, using wget, curl, Python requests, or any other convenient tool, determine the content type returned by the M4A GET and the MP3 GET?

Comment: Also what OS are you using? And what browser?

Comment: I am using a mac with chrome.  Let me see if I can see the content-type

Comment: Also, one strange thing is that, it doesn't execute the 'print request.path' which might suggest that it isn't even requesting the m4a.

Comment: Those are the *request* headers. What is the `Content-Type:` in the *response* headers?

Comment: Looks like there is no `Content-Type:`   Headers({'date': ['Thu, 17 Mar 2016 16:46:19 GMT'], 'server': ['TwistedWeb/15.4.0']})

If I add `request.setHeader("Content-Type","audio/mp4a-latm")`  it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works if you change audio/mp4a-latm to audio/mp4